# object storage image response type to base64 in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, object-storage, ibm-cloud-storage

I'm trying to retrieve data from Object Storage. We have api to get those image files through which I got below formatted data.

```
����\u0000\u0010JFIF\u0000\u0001\u0001\u0000\u0000\u0001\u0000\u0001\u0000\u0000��\u0000C\u0000\b\u0006\u0006\u0007\u0006\u0005\b\u0007\u0007\u0007\t\t\b\n\f\u0014\r\f\u000b\u000b\f\u0019\u0012\u0013\u000f\u0014\u001d\u001a\u001f\u001e\u001d\u001a\u001c\u001c $.' \",#\u001c\u001c(7),01444\u001f'9=82<.342��\u0000C\u0001\t\t\t\f\u000b\f\u0018\r\r\u00182!\u001c!22222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222��\u0000\u0011\b\u0001,\u0000�\u0003\u0001\"\u0000\u0002\u0011\u0001\u0003\u0011\u0001��\u0000\u001a\u0000\u0000\u0003\u0001\u0001\u0001\u0001\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0001\u0002\u0003\u0000\u0004\u0005\u0006��\u00007\u0010\u0000\u0001\u0004\u0001\u0003\u0002\u0005\u0002\u0004\u0005\u0004\u0002\u0003\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0001\u0000\u0002\u0003\u0011!\u0004\u00121AQ\u0013\"aq�\u0005�\u00142��#3B��RS��r�Cb���\u0000\u0019\u0001\u0001\u0001\u0001\u0001\u0001\u0001\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0001\u0002\u0003\u0004\u0005��\u0000%\u0011\u0001\u0001\u0000\u0002\u0001\u0004\u0002\u0003\u0000\u0003\u0001\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0001\u0002\u0011\u0012\u0003\u00131Q!2\u0004\u0014A\"a����\u0000\f\u0003\u0001\u0000\u0002\u0011\u0003\u0011\u0000?\u0000����Fp�\u0015k\u000e���\u0004a\u0000\u0005QMY�@�!h\u0003���vG� \u0005�\u000fO�P+���1\u0018��E�\b@J@�EB/\u0001!\u001e`(ڊG7v\u000f�ֹ��v�k\u0019\tHA�ᕺ\u000eʎk\\r��\u0014\u0013��-]��=v@�J)\u000f�]ÎS�X=E._\u0013kA ��\u0015r\u0002L��Q���Z�v+\u0004 ^�,��U�\u001e��SWt\u0002o|���% �\u0018MiL���I\u0007�!�\u0011\r�9D\f�\u0019�\nE���\n\u001c'\u001d�5�\u0004�<�Ԡ[g*���(���+��\u0015�- �m�\"�U���O�PF�V��@�\u0018QR��ɇ=���9X\u000e��?0HG\u001b?6o�YNf\u0005\u000e)\u0018X�\b\u001a�T�X*Z�u�\u0016Lಃ�\u0002�B��Dh���\u0006��\u000b\u0000K�\u001c\u000eB�Vt�t��M\n\u0019�xdt�\u000e�\u0005��\u000b\u0000��+u쵪\r�\u000f�:��,���\u0017\u0000M\u000e:�=4߉�I���\u0015\u0005+�\u0010-O���\u0014{��h�J@�E����**E���\n��� \u001c�maq�[R���\u000b���ְx!ݍ�T��\u0000���\u001c�[觧w�?��WAnT�\u000e\u000b*��O+(�������V�-�\u000e#���M\u0003+ُB��r�5�6�%k�\u001d�7]\u000f����?��at�@[x[��=�θ�^3��5@*27��\u0015�U�!�\u0018Q ��v19Ҹ\u0011�T��\u001c\u001568�\u000er�c\u0013�#@weA\u001fa]��\u0002;�)���I��R\u0001�t�����'c\u0013�\u0002�3Hl'�Q޶�j~�>�t�7�/�k��[���O���ι�\u000fe\u001dDE�w�4�K�\u0003�֧�Okܯ\u000e\u0018�\u001f\u0011-p�vl7tW�h���e��טc�\u0005e�ݬ���gp�?�1�\u0000�\u0010/Rf#o<,J���}��m�V��!�YGu$�J��ĭiB`��ևTj�!$a`\u001cz\u0015`\u0002۾�&\u001a��\u001e��d\u0000-k,Q\u001a�k@��Po\bZ_T@@VAdT�\t���JBh�p�;�ే�-�\u0014F:�G�\u000bh~���rɬ��(i�%���L ��\u0002��fj`d�\u001bcŃT�E��\u0015��d�R\u000bY����y�ᚪ�\u00144�Sd�\u0001�{\u001d\u001bKn�S�\u000fc��\u001e�TG��\u001a�\u001d�.y5L\u001e�R\u0019�3�n\r\u0007\u0000z����5E�\u001e�)��\u001c���k���l�U���w����w�'�K\fڭ;\"\u00125�Ӊpy!��X\u0004�\u001b8I-\u001e�\u0000�G��;��E��\t���և\u0006��\r���U$��Z�2\u00174��da �ڼQW�\u001d�d�\u0006�D�\u0012汌2�4��l\u0011�+��Q�#��\f��\u0000UX\u0006�w�&���\u0005\u001c\u001b�<�\u0016�4m\u0014��A���Xed\u001bJ.\u0012}S��=\u0014�p\u0011v�$��5|�����\r�3J� �;\u001e6�@=��660\u0006��\u0001�\u0002��\u001b^湏\rh���׺he�d��o\u0017G�\u0006|m~��k�\u0011V��\u0000\u0001\u0000ik���I\f'\u0000�f�?�b�Ia:��ѝ�\u001d��������M�}��3��6�l���Փ���\u001b\u0014e���%\b����\\���Ʈ�O�p\td�\u0013!�\u0016��\u001f&�6+��Ul�b�I�k�<1\u001d\u0013�~�MQ߃�E�X\u0018ִ1��\"�TOs��E��ӱڷk\u001dr\u0002�����k�_f�{\u0003�*\b\u001d\u0016�G1�{ex.c�m\u0014\u0005��\u0000z��]��=�\t\u0018$�[��M\u0012G��Kbf�\u0003��\u0000�\u000emy�f\b�4\f�J\u001a\u001d�\u0002\b�Ů}L��M�ҽ�6��ky%�3�����\u001cN�\"�h�������1���9�p<ۍ�\u0000r���F\u000e�F\u0007�^\u001avQ;�\u0016O���\n��^�!�\u001d�m����j�K�\u000e�T^��;�+D������\u000e�o�Zm��+\u0018}a|���\u0000��4��V��C�8X8 �\u0000.i\u0019<��l�k\u001c+\r6>AGF�Lpm�L�^\u000e\u001c\u001bX���&�JR�\rv��4Sj\u0003C�l.\u0000�cv�}$�k�\u001c��\u0006<Ph\u000e���M\u000e��y��=��\u001f����5���6�\u0016\r��d���7lt�P�\u001f��c���\r��G�����9ުnx�Bwx\u0006I����\u0000���fŇ\u001d����\u0016�\">�!��\"\u0001��h2�`8�6��\u0007�x��]���\u0000I\u0000Y�)�\u0000Q|n�ۜ\u001b�\u00065���o�4�t��<oq\u0018\u000f-k�\u000e\u001d\u001b\u0007B��+�Z�4��\na�<�\u000fW,\\��K�ޔ>�o)5 �\u0007S�H\u0016(�Hٲ\u001a�\u0017\u0011�*\\�ώ��ޗ�P\u0016��$o�$,�˜I]\u0005�f��%�7\n\u0019�+�\u001d{p��u��=M���&�ˎI���\u0018{c����_ɛ�\u0000\u0019���\u0000�w=Gl\u000f\u001f�p5�U�}��\\�%Ӏt��\b��>&��\u0014�t���/+0�Pe \t�k����\u0018�t���K&�'2i\u0018]eѐ��h��בK�6�D֗\u0017\u0010+s�*�\\۫\u0017�+�\u0005dd�W,�4�#�!#�\u000e���z�^oԴ��a��W\u000f\n`�2 ?(<��\u0005+�=�\u001c)\u001a�\u0017�\u0013����{�!�x��Gc��e�u���bq�4���\u0019T)�\u0013�N#���St09��F^����m�=\u0017�ߪM�{\u0019\u001c%�������R�`A�H�T����\u0019f\u000e��o�#\u000e�\u001e\rrH�h�O�׹�\u001b���Xʼv�S�a��s��;u�X�b��띫ә\u001dVזc�,�z�\\���W'��V�T\u001d\u0012���\u001cM\u0003x4�K\u0018\bkk�sx��o\u0010R�\fyr��<f��\u000f\nmcZ����J��\u000f\u0016��p�-nx[��]E�vK\u001aI�E��w�����/\u0018��~�+�]�\u0001ܧ�3�\u0002x\n\u0010\u000b$�E4Ӷ)\b\fs����\u0006I\u0003)���5��ꤞ-\\\u001e\u0011aa\u000e��h��>�V��\u0001�2،{�z�\u0015�$�P��=��\u0002� Վ\u0013j��7�b���\u000bj��H'����闠\u0011'\u000b�ku����\u0000�ǅ��\u001c\u001b�WL^#4�%~��>�����(f�ĵ�i#�\u000f\nnwu�?K6�8\u0004e�t\u0019\u0001�W�\u0003k=�ҏ�&�j�\u0000\u000f�y\u001b\u0014l�|Ji$�0x�q��]��B⼝\u000b�\u000f�ifv��D=�C��\u0003<�A�(�DL���u\u0005�4f��Jq���s�K�[��=�r�\u001b��1ۘ\\��܀a����\u0006N?e���l�Ѵ��|M�N\u0003l\u0002�|���W�\u001e��&ǵ�\u000f�N/\u0000�{�\fdo.`�|���^su����M�� 9ܙ3^P\u000e8^��K�1��+\u0007�O�z��P>�^Jm�SY�AM�(q\u0007�\t��\r\u000eQO�����VA�i�{T�\u0016K /n�)i\u0007���I�o�'��.C�6�K\u001b�{'��\u000b톨�\u001d�G\u0006����e�\f��\u0011\u000b\u0001s�/��֓��h�(/;�Z�D�\u001b#��Z��v�ih��laRv66��5Os\u0003KZ\u001aK\\����\u0002�M#��4c�;�Tt��\u0011�\f����+w�b�\t�\u0000sZ]�h�\u0001\u0000�E\u0006�\u001bf�`\u000e�\u0000\u000e�n?ub�yB�\u0007)��\u0003\u0000��0�@\u001c\u0014��N�\u0000yA��<\u001b\u000bv\u0000�I b������8\u00198����^F.�~M�������\u000b\"��)����9\u001b����쉻���O�(��U�.Ed\b��k@~\u00169)m\u0012o!\u0006��x!.k%\u0010~�\u001f\u0014�\u000b(�Jp����\f��w�'�o��\u0002�n\u0002]/�y�]\u000b\u001d/�\\����\u001a<�͏���Cw�k\u001a\u001dUu����k�\u0003�\u0017F@\u0012�j�\u0001\u0014@\"���5�;�D\u001c��<z��rǼn\u0004q�#��w��I%ԴK!k�o�g�~k+�4��\u000f{ay���\u0006�֓Vz\u000bWc���1�E�{\u0001~�]4�2�6�\u0006��\u001f�Rv����H��J�T�谋$U�\u001c`c��q.�s��\u0000n�dP\u0017^���J�!�U�\u0013y*\u000e9Us�T]V��kn�\u0012�D\u0010z�`m\u0013��A�nJ\rx�jţK\u0014\u0000\u001c,�U���tGt.?���U{�\u0016�����g#�\\\u001b6V:V\\#Yy5�E-a3B��\u000eU\u0003Mg\u000b\u0000\u0007D��3�\u000f'��,p�h�#d�����O\u0018wu\u0007j'v�F�x�wyG�Y��p�y6�Å�Ю'��\u0000�h\u0004�.9�{\u001b8Z�����ԺH�����F�h�\u0004\u001eފz�>�O��H�N�@�I\u0018opI�|���\b�\u0011i�\r�'��\u0001\u0005��;��'���S��\u0004\u0011�=\u0013����\u0016�\u001b�I\u0006\"�ƌ����_7\u001dmM�J�\u001e�<H�Ɯ�\u0000\u000eh\u0000o?�v�\u00042��|ms�<��2\u000f��~\u0002�ӰJd.{��\u000eq \u001f@��\u0013C*o\u0000�\r�j%s�q87c{\u001c��LM(�-#��5�\u000bX@\u0003H�MT\u0010�[�\u0002\u000fT۰�,����,��8s]�ס�Z�$yqfעW�F\u00010�\u0000�=\u0017��m+�q\u000e��\b+\u0012��\u0019T#�r��V\u0013=A�P\u0007���݅�G\u0014R\u0012T�l�J���IS<�]iOu\u0015��Z��}�\u001e\u0016\u001d��\b\u0002�\n(,\u00100�Y-��zf�\u001cݮ���T\u0018��k�\u000b����>\u001e�%u~5�f6���\\�\u0007\u0013�R\u0013\\��z���p�\u001dl᠝��\u001f�Ju��D�WjQ��!u)����+&�s��\u0003ѫ�MT濈\u0007�\u0000��x�j\u000f~\u0013����\u0017�'�矰Rv�V���O\u0018\u001f���Rs���p���q��4��\u0000��H_'�����S�{�}z�<���_%�\u00009�`���#�D\u0007u��ey���\u001b��+��-��\u0000qߢ\u0003&��=3i�/f�[�#��\u0010�\u0006D��?�c�����j\u0019�>��~�\td\u0007��K���Ny{5\u001aI^k�h���)�/f�謎�\u0012\u000f\t\u0003�U ]Aa�n\u0003�{ ��h�\ne�eM�P3�\u0005I��q�I$��ғ�\u0007�\u0000{��\u001fu'?\u0016�pa\"ɳ�)$=B�=�w�!>�d���TP;>�86k����\u0000)��\u0000�d\u0016����Pz\u0004o��\u000f\u001e�xϪ\u0017Y��Ɂ�A���!��b{elz\u0014\u0002�U�� }>R���P]|,�ub���=�:�J^k�!7�H�z��s�������ϳ��g\b�烏�+�\u0007d\u000eze\u0002o\u0002�#�zעG����Sy�\u0010\u0007sv���۔�J�;`��Åt���\r��N>�*ҍ��\u0017��\u0007\u0016\u0002$�WB�\u001cs��#d���;�ϲ\u0006��c�Z�q}��\u0005���\t���{$$�\u0012�@�\u0014��\u0016;����I&�\u0015�\u000f\\����Ss��!!\u0019ʃ���Ac%w*e����(]�u�Ү��\u001a\u0019K��@<��v2�b�P�携@�\u0006?���m\u0000l₥t\u0002Ґ7n'\b����\u0015��O�@qk\u001ex�C��H�#�R\u0006�%\u0012�9?(�?�\u0014ۍ�a%�v����ɠo�,�ʑ~h�\u000b�p~�\u0005�zתR�u�\u000e�R34\u000e~\n��-o$ ��i�:,���F\u001c)��VE�zn��\u001e/��:Q��\\��\u0017\u000e�a�\u001bꮑgI�\u00153%ݕ\u0019\t����F!�S���(��L\u000b���\u001a�:ߢ�`��\"�\u0011АJ�����7\b��=���\t�Kw���p�xB���v߀W��l�ye�.�Tz��ߏT\f�\f\u0010��4�'\u0012�\u001ey+~v4�$�9F�\u0015�LmÜߒ����rO�� XR9\u0006�\"�v��L\u00166\u0013����\u001b\u001fܮC�|{-��N\u0011�uӟB�ډ�ˈ=���|���P\u0012^��\u000e�8�����\u0003�$�E�n�X\u000erp���\u00068�e�v��t�\u000f��"
```

How can I convert this encrypted data to base 64?

Answer (score 0):

You can likely use this library - https://github.com/ninjatronic/angular-base64 to encode that string as base64.